# Setting default APN

Tags: android

I want set an default apn in android gingerbread. Any1 know the solution please try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to customize your network settings. There is [an entry](http://source.android.com/porting/customization.html#androidNetCustPlat) in the Android Documentation for that.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was running into is that the default APNs are not editable. Even if you add an APN, and set it to be default, the device falls back to the origina default when attempting some types of data transmission such as MMS.

I found an application, APN Backup and Restore on Market.  I used it to back up the default APNs, delete the defaults, and then create the APN I want.